# Automatically update a div with html markup, stackoverflow-style

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, markup

Does anyone know how Stackoverflow does the 'preview box' which is below the textarea in which questions and answers are fed? Basically I suppose one could use '.clone()' with jQuery, but then it would not render html markup (e.g. `<b>` or `<br />` and so on) as the div wouldn't be reloaded.

I know that stackoverflow uses ' * ' to markup bold text etc. but for my project 'real' markup will be used, i.e. for bold there is a button that would include `<b>` around the selected text.

I'm still learning this stuff, but just as a hint I suppose I should be looking at something AJAX-like, but haven't been able to find anything really like this particular case!

Thanks!

Comment: You could AJAX it to be parsed with php using bbcode http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to show the html written inside a textarea just take its value and copy inside a preview element, smthg like

```
$('#preview-div').html($('textarea').val())
```

if you need to show it while the user is typing just call this statement inside a `keyup` event handler of the textarea

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
   $('#preview-div').html($(this).val());
});
```

anyway be **aware** of input typed by the user: it's better if you always sanitize the markup before showing on the preview element.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YX9Eq/

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in how Stack Overflow does it, you want to know about [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Basically what you want to do is get the value of the textbox you're writing in, throw that into a Markdown web service via AJAX (or something similar), let the web service parse it for you, then get the response and slap it into a waiting `DIV`.

AFAIK, StackOverflow uses [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) to parse its text. You can quickly create a web service via C# using the same library.

Comment: I thank you for the comment! I'll keep it in mind for future reference